# Comparing performance with and without an audience on the same individuals

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons

We have a set of students in which every student does the following:

A task on its own and then the same task on its own with an audience.
A task in competition and then the same task in competition with an audience

We measure the time that took every student to complete each task

All the students did all of the conditions. They performed the task on their own, and being observed by an audience of 20 people. They performed the task at the same time as another student (i.e., just the two of them with no audience), and when they were both being observed by an audience of 20 people.

I have the data set for anyone that wants to look at it.

My question is what test to use?

I was thinking some thing like repeated measures anova or a paired t-test at the differences of the two events.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do observation and competition pressure make students quicker at completing the task?

That's the question in the problem that we want to answer.

Comment: There are several kinds of comparisons you might want to make. These include: Audience vs. no audience; alone vs. with competition. So you need to tell us what you want to know. Also, the kind of test may depend on the type of data you have. In general, times to complete tasks are often not normal. In that case, ANOVA and t tests might not work so well. I think it would help to see at least some of your data.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VgvaRAsvsPiGoCNZqA2pv5ZY98B_Gmr5/view?usp=sharing the data set that you asked

Comment: Welcome to CV! Please edit your question using the button below it to include a moee informative title. This can help future visitors with similar questions, and it will also attract more answers. For example: "Comparing performance with and without an audience on the same individuals"